SSH connection refused
I hope someone can help us with the following problem. We've installed two new Ubuntu 24.04 machines a few weeks ago. For security reason, we change the default SSH port (f.e. 5643). Since Ubuntu 24.04 uses ssh.socket, we found out that we have to do something like this to change the port:
systemctl edit ssh.socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=
ListenStream=5643

systemctl restart ssh.socket

After restarting the socket, we were able to connect to SSH via the new port. Everything worked fine (also with some restarts of the machines) until a few days ago. We were not able to connect to both machines anymore (SSH: connection refused). We've tried our individual port and also the default one (22), both gave us a connection refused. A port scan also showd us that both ports were closed.
We had to connect via VNC to check whats going on. service ssh status showed us that it was running (triggered by ssh.socket). We tried to remove the override.conf and restarted the service / socket, but we were still not able to connect to SSH. Only the following solution fixed the problem:
systemctl disable --now ssh.socket
systemctl enable --now ssh.service

Does anybody know if we did something wrong? I'm still wondering why it worked for weeks and suddenly stopped on both VPS machines (both are also hosted at different providers).

Did you install a firewall like ufw? Does the one line systemctl restart ssh.socket does the same job as the disable and then enable?

Hey, ufw seems to have been installed automatically when the system was created. The funny thing is that everything worked fine for weeks, even after several system reboots. Then we didn't log in for 1-2 weeks and suddenly the SSH login no longer works. The only thing the systems have in common is that they have Ubuntu 24.04 installed and we had to change the SSH port via the socket configuration, not in the sshd_config like on the previous systems. Automatic updates were also activated on both machines, has there been an update recently that could have caused this behavior?

Why did you change this in systemctl with editing the socket instead of changing sshd_config to change the listen port?  you migiht've broken SSH by doing what you're doing

With Ubuntu 24.04, socket-based activation for SSH is used on systems that use systemd.
Quoting from SSHd now uses socket-based activation (Ubuntu 22.10 and later) on Ubuntu Discourse:

In Ubuntu 22.10, Ubuntu 23.04, and Ubuntu 23.10, on upgrade users who
had configured Port settings or a ListenAddress setting in
/etc/ssh/sshd_config will find these settings migrated to
/etc/systemd/system/ssh.socket.d/addresses.conf.

Also...

In Ubuntu 24.04 LTS these settings are no longer migrated, but the
port and address settings are pulled dynamically from sshd.conf via a
systemd generator.

Therefore, to configure a non-standard port, do not create a drop-in config file in /etc/systemd/system/ssh.service.d. Instead, configure your server as usual in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.
Edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config and define the following:
port 5643

You indicated that you disabled ssh.socket and enabled ssh.service. Thus, if you want to use socket-based activation, you'll need to revert these changes:
sudo systemctl stop ssh.service
sudo systemctl disable ssh.service
sudo systemctl enable ssh.socket

Reload systemd manager configuration to rerun all generators and reload all unit files:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

Retart ssh.socket service:
sudo systemctl restart ssh.socket


Documentation has been updated with accurate instructions as of openssh version 1:9.3p1-1ubuntu1.
Per /usr/share/doc/openssh-server/README.Debian.gz

Socket-based activation with systemd
------------------------------------

By default, socket-based activation is used on systems that use
systemd.

The provided ssh.socket unit file sets ListenStream=22. A systemd
generator, sshd-socket-generator, parses the sshd configuration and,
if non-default ListenAddress(s) or Port(s) are configured, generates
corresponding ListenStream= lines in a drop-in configration file for
ssh.socket. To change the port or address ssh.socket is listening on,
edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config (or add a drop-in file to
/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/) as usual and then run:

  systemctl daemon-reload   systemctl restart ssh.socket

See systemd.socket(5) for details.


If you want to disable socket-based activation of SSH, details are outlined in the documentation:

If you do not want to use socket activation for ssh on your system, you
can disable socket activation by masking the generator and re-enabling
ssh.service:

  mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system-generators/
  ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/system-generators/sshd-socket-generator
  systemctl daemon-reload
  systemctl disable --now ssh.socket
  systemctl enable --now ssh.service



Here is what I did when my Ubuntu 24.04.01 Desktop did not allow ssh connection.
I don't know about ssh.socket and I don't see it among the active services. What I know is that ssh.service should be loaded active running for ssh working.
Check first whether that is the case for you.
$> systemctl -t service -all | grep ssh 

Normally, you should see the reply to the command as
 ssh.service                      loaded active running OpenBSD Secure Shell server

If there is no response to the above command, then either ssh.service has not been started or ssh may not even be installed.
Check whether the ssh has been installed.
$> apt-cache policy openssh-server

If the reply by the system looks like the one below, it is not installed.
openssh-server:
  Installed: (none)

First, the ssh needs to be installed.
Note: openssh-server is the same as ssh by now. (Ubuntu 24.04.01)
(All below is for all to copy and paste conveniently.)
$> sudo apt-get install ssh

Then start the ssh.service
$> sudo systemctl start ssh

To verify the solution; the following also may be used [1]
$> service ssh status

     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-11-20 13:37:24 PST; 23h ago
TriggeredBy: ● ssh.socket
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 1323 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1325 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 392)
     Memory: 4.7M (peak: 5.8M)
        CPU: 1.002s
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─1325 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"

The following may be used for debug. [2]
$> ssh -vvv username@host 

References:
[1] 16.04 SSH connection refused: hunting down root-cause
[2] SSH connection getting refused
Credits:

https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru
https://askubuntu.com/users/7035/luis-alvarado
https://askubuntu.com/users/37577/goddard

